# How do I estimate the transmission distance of a 50 watt 2m radio?

Tags: antenna, ham-radio

Can anyone point me to a reference for calculating (estimating) the transmission distance of a 50-watt, 2-meter radio? The transmitting antenna will probably be 5-7 meters above ground. Probably the same height for the receiving antenna.

Thanks!

Comment: On 2m, I seem to recall 10W from a 1/4 wave vertical (vehicle roof mounted) being sufficient to get into a repeater that was 20 or 30 miles away. So 50W should do considerably better than that, though you will still likely have blind spots behind mountains.

Comment: @Just: All else being equal, distance goes with the cube square root of power.  So 50W should go 2.2 times as far as 10W *unless there are obstacles between the antennas*, in which case it will end at about the same distance in both cases.

Comment: Given enough antenna height and suitable antennae range is sensibly unlimited. Antennae characteristics are so fundamental to this question at this frequency that an answer cannot be sensibly given without some sort of antenna spec. Note that 5 to 7 metres is excellent but that diffraction with ground issues will be your distane limit constraint at very great distances. "2 metres" sounds like a ham band spec. Go away ! :-)

Comment: @Olin Lathrop - well, 2.2 times as far seems considerable, doesn't it?

Comment: Just get a licenced freq in the business VHF band ~150mhz. Its only around $100 for 10 years! Why anyone would run unlicenced i dont know!

Comment: @john how does this answer the question? Are you implying that licensure ensures one's ability to perform a calculation such as this? It's seems this technical question had been hijacked by a discussion about licensing. How about sticking to the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing that the ground between transmitter and receiver is flat the following formula gives the distance to the horizon:

\$ D =1.2\sqrt{H} \$

where H is the antenna height above the ground in feet and D is the distance to horizon in miles. You then have to double this distance so that both antennas see the horizon.

So with antenna height of 7 meters (approximately 22 feet) this gives

\$ 1.2 \sqrt{22} = 1.2 * 4.7 = 5.6\mbox{ miles} \$

Double this to give 11.2 miles.

This assumes that both stations are at the same height above sea level.  If one station is higher than the other, the answer will be greater than 11.2 miles. Providing that there are no obstacles between the two stations (buildings, hills, mountains, etc.) it should be possible to cover this distance with only 1W.

Comment: Your caps lock key seems to be stuck on.  It would be a good idea to fix that before posting anything else here.

Comment: Showing that each antenna can see each other is half the answer. A link budget would make this answer will be more general.   Received power (dBm)=Transmitted power (dBm)+Gains (dB)−Losses (dB)   and stating that the received power must be greater than the sensitivity of the receiver and more for the desired SNR

Comment: Gains include the antenna gain. One of the losses is the _free space path loss_  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be reliable, then you are talking about line of sight, if not direct than to a repeater on a tall building, mountaintop, or satellite. In most of these cases, 50 W should be sufficient with non-terrible antennas and no undue interference.

There are some occasional over-the-horizon atmospheric propagation modes for 2 m (and even meteor ionization trails for infrequent packets) which you can read about in the ARRL handbook, but you can't depend on them.

You would need a huge antenna farm to get enough directionality to do moonbounce with 50 watts.

Answer (score 0):

50W?  Are you sure?  That's not something you hack around with.  That will require the proper licenses, in which case there should be someone envolved that knows what they are doing.

At 150 MHz (2m wavelength), it's largely line of sight, but can go thru small stuff like trees with some attenuation.  You'll get a little refraction around the earth, but things like large structures will create dead spots, and sometimes hot spots.  Think of it this way, this is a bit past the commercial FM band.

In short, if you've got two directional antennas pointed at each other, there'll be no problem if they're within sight of each other.  Anything else diminishes rapidly.  Of course if they are line of sight you don't need anywhere near 50W.

Comment: Yeah, 50 watts. One of the radios being considered is 65-watts. I don't have a license yet  but it's in the works. The question came up while discussing a research project and how we could transmit data from a site without reliable cell coverage.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you find something wrong you should say what it is.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I did not downvote, but starting out by telling people that they should not be doing to project is really not an answer. You were probably downvoted for that. A user wanting to get a calculation for range has nothing to do with their license status. I know a few HAM radio guys whom do not know how to do this calculation properly, and I only know a few whom know how to do this calculation.